# Jenkins: build job regardless revision

Tags: jenkins

I use GitHub as CSV. I want my Jenkins job to be built each time I trigger it regardless revision. 
Unfortunately, if there are no any new pushes my job refuses to build:

> [poll] Latest remote head revision on
>   refs/heads/My_Brench is:
>   f405ced00e0e64ece71658a1b179ef4ed0db2deb - already built by 13.
>   Job status: [My Job] subjob has no changes since last build.  Using strategy:
>   Default

How can I avoid this skipping `already built by 13` and build it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

With that plugin you can define boolean parameter `hudson.scm.multijob.build.always` in your parent job and if the value of this parameter is true all your sub-projects will be built regardless of SCM changes.

[image]